# Element search using some kind of node number in DOM Tree

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I am looking for a recursive search strategy that JavaScript can offer (JQuery also welcome). Right now I can look for an element if I have its id, className or tagName known, or I can also find though other criteria that are based on css properties and element index in parent node.

So basically what I am trying to accomplish is search for a node based on its x,y position (this is easy part), then store some kind of reference to this node in memory (outside JavaScript code) and later re-use that reference (maybe this reference is a node number in dom tree) for locating the same element again.

In this HTML page, elements wont have any id, class name.

How can I get a serializable reference to any arbitrary element in DOM?

**EDIT**
I am working on android's webview where at first Java code invokes JavaScript routines and it gets element (number I am looking for) and in later part of java code it pass that element number to javascript again for locating the same element.

Comment: Why the downvote? This question looks fine.

Comment: @BlueIce Probably because there is no code? However the question goes deeper than simply requesting code. I'm with you.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean with: "*reference to this node in memory (outside javascript code)*" ?

Comment: @Mouser, first i get js element object thru normal searching for example find() method in jQuery but then i am not allowed to use the same instance of object again. There will be Java code that takeover which should store some type of string identifier for this element and later invoke java script method code again with that identifier. Btw I am working on android's webview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> store some kind of reference to this node in memory (outside javascript code) and later re-use that reference (maybe this reference is a node number in dom tree) for locating the same element again.

In its simplest form:

- store a list of child positions, counting from the `document`
- iterate that list to retrieve the element in question

i.e.

```
function refElement(elem) {
    var positions = [],
        position;

    while (elem) {
        position = 0;
        while (elem.previousElementSibling) {
            position++;
            elem = elem.previousElementSibling;
        }
        positions.unshift(position);
        elem = elem.parentElement;
    }
    return positions.join();
}

function getElement(ref) {
    var positions = ref.split(/,/),
        elem = document;

    while (elem && positions.length) {
        elem = elem.children[positions.shift()];
    }
    return elem;
}
```

Test:

```
var e = document.getElementsByTagName("TEXTAREA")[0];
var ref = refElement(e);
console.log(ref)                   // 0,4,6,1,0,2,1,4,6,0,0,1
console.log(e === getElement(ref)) // true
```

Should be needless to say: This solution assumes an immutable document structure between calls of `refElement()` and `getElement()`.

Comment: this looks a workable solution, however we have to make an expensive call to refElement() for a recursion that already happened during getElementsByTagName().

Comment: Expensive? I don't understand.

Comment: ah, it will not be that expensive because we only iterating for tags and not for individual text nodes.

Comment: It would not be expensive one way or the other. It is not expensive as an iterative implementation, it would not be as a recursive implementation. `refElement()` easily runs a lot more than 100,000 times per second on my aging laptop.

Comment: yes at first i thought it is recursive for entire dom, but this code is elegant.. thanks much :)